# How to adjust vertical space between soft returns?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting

There are some fonts that have a lot of reserved vertical space.  I know that I can adjust that spacing between paragraphs by changing the `leading`, and this allows me to move the second line of text until it touches the text above it.

However, changing the `leading` has no effect on soft returns (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>).

How can I get the same effect without converting the text to paths?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Leading should still adjust space between two lines of text with a soft return, hard return or no return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leading has effect on **shift + enter**, and **regular enter** is spaced (more) by paragraph spacing. 
Basically leading is a set measurement doesn't matter whether you did regular enter of shift enter, and If you want to make the space even larger between paragraph (regular enters) then add paragraph spacing

> Now if you really want to start working properly for print you have to
>   start working with **baseline grid** anyway.

Comment: The baseline grid does not work for every type of text. If used, you cannot adjust the spacing between *paragraphs* anymore, other than in entire-line increments.

Comment: You can you will just always jump an entire line, say you want to enlarge the space between paragraphs, enlarge it enough so that it jumps a line, **it is the professional way to work**

Comment: You know, I spent about 15 minutes trying to figure out how to do this before posting my question.  After I read this answer, I went and adjusted the leading (just like I did before) and it immediately adjusted my soft-return!  Go figure!  Thanks for taking the trouble to answer.

Answer (score 1):

First

- you **do not** "adjust the spacing between paragraphs by changing the leading". Instead, you adjust the spacing between the **lines** in a paragraph.

Then

- Leading affects all lines in a paragraph (or in a selection), including lines broken by soft returns.
- A soft return will never signal an end of paragraph in InDesign. A soft return keeps you within the same paragraph.
- A paragraph by definition always ends with a normal return, so multiple paragraphs are just the content between multiple returns.
- In addition to leading, there are the 'space before' and 'space after' paragraph options, which do not affect leading, but just add extra space before or after a paragraph.
- A baseline grid is an advanced feature for formatting large content, but is not necessarily related to this question in particular. Using a baseline grid adds additional rules and restrictions to the leading game.

[image]

Comment: My question wasn't really about how to use leading - it is about how to compensate for the funny vertical height of some fonts; maybe I should have given a different title; I appreciate the detailed explanation.